# Unable to use core Estimator with contrib Predictor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using canned estimators and are struggling with poor predict performance so I'm trying to use tf.contrib.predictor to improve my inference performance. I've made this minimalistic example to reproduce my problems:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

def serving_input_fn():
  x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[1], name='x')
  inputs = {'x': x }
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

input_feature_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=[1])
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=[input_feature_column],
    hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
    model_dir="model_dir\\predictor-test")

estimator_predictor = predictor.from_estimator(estimator, serving_input_fn)

estimator_predictor({"inputs": ["1.0"]})
```

This yields the following exception:

```py
UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Cast string to float is not supported
[[Node: dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/x/ToFloat = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/x/ExpandDims)]]
```

I've tried using `tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver` instead of `ServingInputReceiver` in my `serving_input_fn()`, so that I can feed my model with a numerical tensor which is what I want:

```py
def serving_input_fn():
  x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], name='x')
  return tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver(x, x)
```

but then I get the following exception in my `predictor.from_estimator()` call:

```py
ValueError: features should be a dictionary of Tensors. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would just like to add that everything works perfectly when using the contrib estimator and corresponding `tf.contrib.predictor.from_contrib_estimator()` call. My current strategy is to use the deprecated contrib estimators until predictor moves from contrib to core, but I'm happy to revisit this if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of all of this is not really solid but I got it working and given the size of the community, I'll try to share what I did.

First, I'm running tensorflow 1.5 binaries with this [patch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/15648/commits/17028b527fe6212edf717f06fedfffc59386c54b) applied manually.

The exact code I'm running is this:

```py
def serving_input_fn():
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3500], name='x')
    inputs = {'x': x }

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir="{}/model_dir_{}/model.ckpt-103712".format(script_dir, 3))

estimator_predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_estimator(
                            estimator, serving_input_fn)

p = estimator_predictor(
        {"x": np.array(sample.normalized.input_data)})
```

My case is a bit different than your example because I'm using a custom Estimator but in your case, I guess you should try something like this:

```py
def serving_input_fn():
  x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1], name='x')
  inputs = {'x': x }

  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

estimator = ...

estimator_predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_estimator(
                            estimator, serving_input_fn)

estimator_predictor({"x": [1.0]})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It didn't really get me closer to a solution when using canned estimators, but when using a custom estimator as you suggested it works pretty flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

error is in following line:

```
estimator_predictor({"inputs": ["1.0"]})
```

please put 1.0 out of quotes. Currently it's a string.

Comment: Then I get the following exception: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes.`. I've been thinking that since `ServingInputReceiver` only accepts a single string input I had to do it this way. `TensorServingInputReceiver` should accept float I think, but I can't get it to work as described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

After having worked on this for a couple of days, I want to share what I have done. The following code is also available from https://github.com/dage/tensorflow-estimator-predictor-example

TL;DR: predictor works best with custom estimators and the performance increase is massive.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time

FEATURES_RANK = 3   # The number of inputs
LABELS_RANK = 2     # The number of outputs

# Returns a numpy array of rank LABELS_RANK based on the features argument.
# Can be used when creating a training dataset.
def features_to_labels(features):
    sum_column = features.sum(1).reshape(features.shape[0], 1)
    labels = np.hstack((sum_column*i for i in range(1, LABELS_RANK+1)))
    return labels

def serving_input_fn():
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, FEATURES_RANK], name='x')     # match dtype in input_fn
    inputs = {'x': x }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    net = features["x"]         # input
    for units in [4, 8, 4]:     # hidden units
        net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        net = tf.layers.dropout(net, rate=0.1)
    output = tf.layers.dense(net, LABELS_RANK, activation=None)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=output, export_outputs={"out": tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(output)})

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, output)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss)

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

# expecting a numpy array of shape (1, FEATURE_RANK) for constant_feature argument
def input_fn(num_samples, constant_feature = None, is_infinite = True):
    feature_values = np.full((num_samples, FEATURES_RANK), constant_feature) if isinstance(constant_feature, np.ndarray) else np.random.rand(num_samples, FEATURES_RANK)
    feature_values = np.float32(feature_values) # match dtype in serving_input_fn
    labels = features_to_labels(feature_values)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(({"x": feature_values}, labels))
    if is_infinite:
        dataset = dataset.repeat()
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,  
    model_dir="model_dir\\estimator-predictor-test-{date:%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S}".format(date=datetime.datetime.now()))

train = estimator.train(input_fn=lambda : input_fn(50), steps=500)
evaluate = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=lambda : input_fn(20), steps=1)

predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_estimator(estimator, serving_input_fn)

consistency_check_features = np.random.rand(1, FEATURES_RANK)
consistency_check_labels = features_to_labels(consistency_check_features)

num_calls_predictor = 100
predictor_input = {"x": consistency_check_features}
start_time_predictor = time.clock()
for i in range(num_calls_predictor):
    predictor_prediction = predictor(predictor_input)
delta_time_predictor = 1./num_calls_predictor*(time.clock() - start_time_predictor)

num_calls_estimator_predict = 10
estimator_input = lambda : input_fn(1, consistency_check_features, False)
start_time_estimator_predict = time.clock()
for i in range(num_calls_estimator_predict):
    estimator_prediction = list(estimator.predict(input_fn=estimator_input))
delta_time_estimator = 1./num_calls_estimator_predict*(time.clock() - start_time_estimator_predict)

print("{} --> {}\n  predictor={}\n  estimator={}.\n".format(consistency_check_features, consistency_check_labels, predictor_prediction, estimator_prediction))
print("Time used per estimator.predict() call: {:.5f}s, predictor(): {:.5f}s ==> predictor is {:.0f}x faster!".format(delta_time_estimator, delta_time_predictor, delta_time_estimator/delta_time_predictor))
```

On my laptop I get the following results:

```py
[[0.55424854 0.98057611 0.98604857]] --> [[2.52087322 5.04174644]]
  predictor={'output': array([[2.5221248, 5.049496 ]], dtype=float32)}
  estimator=[array([2.5221248, 5.049496 ], dtype=float32)].

Time used per estimator.predict() call: 0.30071s, predictor(): 0.00057s ==> predictor is 530x faster!
```

Comment: I concur, I also got this crazy improvements on my end. Also using the predictor as just a simple function is so nice it looks like magic.